# Iteration through multiple while controller using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have an API service, which accepts JSON input and gives multiple JSON in a single response.

In first CSV, I have endpoint which I will access by HTTP request, and the input JSON which I will post with it.

In second CSV, I have API endpoints, index of response JSON, and unique id in response which I need to validate.

Sample CSV 1

```
/API/EndPoint/1
json_request_post_1.json
/API/EndPoint/2
json_request_post_2.json
```

Sample CSV 2

- API Endpoints
- index of JSON response
- Unique id in respective responses

Data:

```
 /API/EndPoint/1
 0
 CS-3736f6a7b0f05d38abf69435a261fb557c5d58ca6deacedc06480d4032603105
 /API/EndPoint/1
 1
 CS-51c1c894d1b96fc93d458f152029d9ffe3efda81c099ea1294e085e53a53b1a5
 /API/EndPoint/2
 0
 CS-2580621b29babb61037e386f127e9cc7060c691100701982c6c07458ea86a924
 /API/EndPoint/2
 1
 CS-3c5166f79e23c8c227368de9d3bb7d1eabd38c191ea519054fee249d091c67a1
 /API/EndPoint/2
 2
 CS-5f3a65daf8fc289b4e5ec174cac4be4ea0c28d0248faf81515865c6c48819f87
```

So I need to send a request to `/API/EndPoint/1` once and need to verify twice if `id[0]` and `id[1]` are getting correct id values.

Then I have to move to `/API/EndPoint/2` and check if `id[0]`, `id[1]` and `id[2]` are getting correct id values.

I have put a `while controller` which contains –

1. HTTP request
2. CSV dataset config based on CSV 1

Inside this `while controller` I have put another `while controller` which contains –

1. A bean shell sampler - return `ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString();`
2. CSV dataset config based on CSV 2
3. JSON path assertion which takes JSON path based on index value of CSV 2 (Column 2).

Is there any way to stop inner loop after `count=2` in first iteration, and start from the same point and do it 3 times in iteration 2. Basically iterate through CSV 2 on repeated values on API endpoints.

Or some other way you would suggest?